# Setting up foreignkeys in loaddata for Django

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have setup two classes, where a user may have multiple access keys.

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

class pets(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

I am trying to preload the tables with data using loaddata through a json file that looks like:

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "middle_name": "G",
        "birthday": "1900-07-21",
        "password": "goforit123",
        "email": "John.Doe@gmail.com"
        },
        "model": "account_data.user",
    "pk": 1
},
{
    "fields": {
        "user": "????"
        "type": "dog",
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "model": "account_data.pets",
    "pk": 1
}
]
```

What do I put in the user for the pet class?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use de pk of the object you want to link:

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "middle_name": "G",
        "birthday": "1900-07-21",
        "password": "goforit123",
        "email": "John.Doe@gmail.com"
    },
    "model": "account_data.user",
    "pk": 1  // This is the pk you have to use
},
{
    "fields": {
        "user": 1,  // Use the pk, in this case you're referencing to John Doe
        "type": "dog",
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "model": "account_data.pets",
    "pk": 1
}
]
```

Comment: Let's say user has already been loaded and you don't know the pk. Is there a way to find it?

Comment: Not here, you don't apply logic in a JSON file. Remember that this is to load initial/test data, so, if you have previuos users add them to this JSON file.

Comment: But is there a way to write code in a .py file to find the foreign key and than generate a .json with the appropriate pk?

Comment: Sure, you could create a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management), like: `python manage.py find_pks` and write some code to explore your DB and write a JSON file there.